# Should the question about accusations be splitted into smaller questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I am writing in reference to this question;

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14426/some-christians-accusation-on-islam-is-satanic-and-fake-religon

In this question, author presents a wall of accusations about Islam. A valid answer should normally address all aspects of the question. However, in this question, rebuttal of all accusations would make the questions too broad. I suggest we should split the question and address each of the accusations separately.

What do you think?